# How do I stop Freeciv from animating every move when observing an AI player?

Tags: freeciv

When observing an AI player on a large map, each turn can take a few minutes, because Freeciv animates every single move by units of the observed player. This is extremely slow. Is there a way to stop Freeciv from showing every single move when observing? I would prefer to only see the end result of each turn.

Freeciv version: 2.5.10

Comment: This is no longer a problem in Freeciv 2.6. In Freeciv 2.6, the user can interact with menus and units while the animation is in progress.